# JCE Editor 2.3.1 Changes HTML in Joomla 3.0

Tags: html, joomla3.0

I am using the code view of JCE editor to add a link around some text. Adding a link through the link functionality gives the same results. When I add the link and save and come back to the code, it has completely reformatted it. Thanks for any help!

Here are the things I have already done:

- Turned off global text filtering already.
- Global parameters for the editor set validate HTML to off.
- In user profile validate HTML is set to off.
- Turned off all the parameters on the plugin parameters for the source code editor.

Here is the code I enter and how it becomes reformatted by JCE Edit:

```
<!-- BEFORE -->
<a class="inline" href="#inline_content">
    <div class="smallTile">
        <img src="/image.jpg" />
        <h4 class="upper">Title</h4>
        <p>
            <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Paragraph</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</a>



<!-- AFTER -->
<a class="inline" href="#inline_content"></a>
<div class="smallTile">
    <a class="inline" href="#inline_content">
        <img src="/image.jpg" />
        <h4 class="upper">Title</h4>
    </a>
    <p>
        <a class="inline" href="#inline_content"></a>
        <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Paragraph</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I would recommend that you take a look at RokPad2 from RocketTheme. Far better source code view editor, doesn't mess up the code, and is free. http://www.rockettheme.com/extensions-joomla/rokpad

Comment: Check to see whether this is JCE by using the TinyMCE editor. I appreciate you think you have caught all the right settings in JCE but that would tell you for sure.